# Safely killing a mySQL query that will not respond to KILL PROCESS

Tags: mysql

Running a regular OPTIMIZE TABLE query on a MYISAM table that usually takes a few minutes has now taken about 3 days. This also happened a week or so ago, but it did complete successfully and I wrongly assumed that the table had been repaired okay, and this time it wouldn't present a problem. Not so...

Last time, the process did not respond to KILL PROCESS and I ended up having to restart mysqld. The error log reported warnings such as:

```
[Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 24974085  user: 'XXXX'
```

And when mysqld restarted, a number of other tables had been left corrupted and had to be rebuilt. Some of these tables are large, and I want to avoid this happening again. I understood that restarting mysqld should safely close tables, but it didn't seem to.

The web services that use the mySQL server will be put into maintenance mode to prevent new queries hitting the DB. But how can I safely close all open tables given that FLUSH TABLES is being blocked by the OPTIMIZE query?

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES;
[etc...]
114 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I *really* don't want 114 tables to have to be repaired. Any advice?

NB: I'm quite aware that the table being optimized will be corrupted and can live with that. I just want to minimize problems with the other tables.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

So FLUSH TABLES accepts a comma-separated list of tables... Maybe it could be as simple as flushing all open tables, but I'm still open to reassurance about this, or any other ideas. Flushing a specific table does remove it from the open tables list so this is looking promising.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/flush.html

Comment: so you want to kill a single query instead of the whole query right ?

Comment: @CodeLover - I want to kill the OPTIMIZE TABLE query that has been running for 3 days. I've just run the OPTIMIZE on a backup and it's took 51 seconds, so something is very wrong with the table/file on the production server. I've run KILL PROCESS on the query and now the status is KILLED. Previously this just did not change until I restarted mysqld which then corrupted a number of other tables. I want to avoid corrupting other tables if I have to restart mysqld.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this all went very smoothly. Steps followed were something like this. I'm not sure if flushing and closing each table separately was overkill, but no tables crashed and total downtime was about 45 mins, so it was worth it:

```
Make a full slave backup
Redirect FQDN for the master to a dead IP so all services are down and master receives no new queries
When master is receiving no new queries, flush and close all tables individually
Stop mysql on master
Ensure OPTIMIZE TABLE does not cause problems for slave if it is replicated out
Stop mysql on slave
Copy all blog tables from slave to master
Restart master
Restart slave
Check for any corrupt tables and allow them to be repaired
Map FQDN back to the master internal IP
Sanity check of posts on main blog
Restart replication on slave and masters 
Make sure replication progresses correctly (multi-master)
Make a full master backup
```